# How to call [UICollectionView reloadData] when it is inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView which has a UICollectionView inside. I assumed that when I called [UITableView reloadData] the collectionView data would also be reloaded but it isn't.

What's happening is the tableview is loaded and the collectionView is loaded with information from an array called placesArray. But when i perform a query, and the placesArray changes, i call reloadData on the Tableview but the collectionView delegate methods are not called again.

I am using AFTableViewCell which I sourced from a tutorial [here](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell)

This is what the AFTableviewCell.h looks like:

```
@interface AFIndexedCollectionView : UICollectionView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;

@end

static NSString *CollectionViewCellIdentifier = @"CollectionViewCellIdentifier";

@interface AFTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) AFIndexedCollectionView *collectionView;

- (void)setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:(id<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>)dataSourceDelegate indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

and AFTAbleViewCell.m

```
@implementation AFIndexedCollectionView

@end

@implementation AFTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) return nil;
    
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 9, 10);
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(44, 44);
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.collectionView = [[AFIndexedCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.collectionView];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    
    self.collectionView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (void)setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:(id<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>)dataSourceDelegate indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.collectionView.indexPath = indexPath;
    NSLog(@"sec = %ld, row = %li", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);
    self.collectionView.tag = indexPath.section;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
@end
```

TableView methods:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeaturedCell";
    
    AFTableViewCell *cell = (AFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (!cell == YES)
    {
        cell = [[AFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(AFTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [cell setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:self indexPath:indexPath];
        cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.section;
        NSInteger index = cell.collectionView.tag;
        CGFloat horizontalOffset = [self.contentOffsetDictionary[[@(index) stringValue]] floatValue];
        [cell.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(horizontalOffset, 0)];
        cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.section;
}
```

Collection View methods

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(AFIndexedCollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return placesArray.count;
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
//// Setting up the cell here
        return cell;
```

I have also tried calling [cell.collectionView reloadData] in the tableView delegate methods with no success.

I hope you can help,

Thanks - Shayne

Comment: Add your viewcontroller datasource methods.

Comment: @ArunAmmannaya Added the methods